# Swift - "attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift2

Xcode 8.1, Swift 2.3, iOS 10.1, And I use Firebase

I registered notices using firebase. And I am trying show notices on uitableview. viewDidLoad() succesfully connection firebase and get value. But I can not list the incoming data.

First I was getting the error "cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't work". After, i use forRow & inSection. But now I'm getting the error that I do not know what it means.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'
```

NoticeViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseStorage

private let reuseIdentifier = "NoticeViewTable"

class NoticeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var aivLoading: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var noticeTableView: UITableView!

    var databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    var usersDict = NSDictionary()

    var noticesArray = [AnyObject]()
    var loggedInUser : AnyObject?



    @IBAction func didTapAddNotice(sender: AnyObject) {

        let mainStorboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let viewController: UIViewController = mainStorboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AddNoticeView")
        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.loggedInUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

        self.aivLoading.startAnimating()
        self.databaseRef.child("notice").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

            self.usersDict = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

            self.noticesArray = [AnyObject]()

            for (userId, details) in self.usersDict {

                let noticeImg = details.objectForKey("noticeImage1") as! String
                let profileImg = details.objectForKey("profileImage") as! String
                let profileName =  details.objectForKey("userName") as! String
                let wage = details.objectForKey("wage") as! String
                let noticeName = details.objectForKey("noticeName") as! String

                if(self.loggedInUser?.uid != userId as? String){
                    details.setValue(userId, forKey: "uId")
                    self.noticesArray.append(details)
                }

                self.noticeTableView?.reloadData()

                self.noticeTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

                self.aivLoading.stopAnimating()


            }

        }) {(error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.noticesArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

        let cell: NoticeViewTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NoticeViewTableViewCell

        let profileImageURL = NSURL(string: self.noticesArray[indexPath.row]["profileImage"] as! String)
        let profileImageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: profileImageURL!)
        cell.profilePic.image = UIImage(data:profileImageData!)

        let noticeImageURL = NSURL(string: self.noticesArray[indexPath.row]["noticeImage!"] as! String)
        let noticeImageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: noticeImageURL!)
        cell.noticeImage.image = UIImage(data:noticeImageData!)


        //add a border and corner radius the images
        cell.profilePic.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = cell.profilePic.frame.size.width/2.0
        cell.profilePic.layer.borderWidth = 1.5


        let profileName = (self.noticesArray[indexPath.row]["userName"] as? String)!
        cell.userName.text = profileName

        let noticeName = (self.noticesArray[indexPath.row]["noticeName"] as? String)!
        cell.noticeName.text = noticeName

        let wage = (self.noticesArray[indexPath.row]["wage"] as? String)!
        cell.wage.text = wage

        return cell

    }

}
```

Comment: 1) Update your question with the actual code causing the error and point out the exact line causing the error. 2) Search on the error. It has been discussed many times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code. Any of them could cause the crash.

- A row is inserted in the table view even if `uid` is not valid.
- `details` is **appended** to the datasource array but **inserted** at index 0 in the table view
- Do not call both `reloadData()` and `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`. Delete `reloadData()`

Answer (score 0):

For other users stumbling upon this question, these errors also arise when trying to update a TableView or CollectionView with no `dataSource` assigned. Make sure the TableView's `dataSource` is connected (when using a storyboard or nib) or assigned programmatically.